# issue with ajax modal popup extender

Tags: controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am facing a problem while displaying two modal popups.
Scenario goes like this:

I display one modal popup on the button click.I have another button inside this modal popup.
When I click on this button, I display another modal popup. Now the problem is that, when I 
display the second popup, the first popup is still clikable.
What should I do so that user cannot click the first popup.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

assuming this has something to do with html:

set the zindex of the second popup to be higher then the first

1st popup:

```
position:relative;
z-index:1;
```

2nd popup:

```
position:relative;
z-index:2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this before... there was some quirk regarding where you placed your Extenders in Relation to their Panels. I can't remember specifically which version ended up working, but you could play around with the following combinations.

e.g.

```
<!-- 2 Seperate Panels & Extenders -->
<ajt:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe1" TargetControlID="pnl1" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1">
   <asp:Button ID="btn1" /> <!-- launches pnl2 popup -->
</asp:Panel>

<ajt:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe2" TargetControlID="pnl2" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnl2">
   Content
</asp:Panel>
```

Vs.

```
<!-- 2 Nested Panels & But separate Extenders -->
<ajt:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe1" TargetControlID="pnl1" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1">
   <asp:Button ID="btn1" /> <!-- launches pnl2 popup -->
   <asp:Panel ID="pnl2">
       Content
   </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel> 
<ajt:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe2" TargetControlID="pnl2" />
```

Vs.

```
<!-- 2 Fully Nested Panels & Extenders -->
<ajt:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe1" TargetControlID="pnl1" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnl1">
   <asp:Button ID="btn1" /> <!-- launches pnl2 popup -->
   <ajt:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe2" TargetControlID="pnl2" />
   <asp:Panel ID="pnl2">
       Content
   </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a background CssClass that greys out the page or you can capture the click in your code behind and tell it to hide the previous popup by calling the externer.hide() method and that will give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues.  Rather than having 2 modal popups, place one panel with the two panels inside it.  The parent panel gets the modal popup extender, while the two inside are hidden / shown based on what button is clicked.  Dependent upon the styles applied to the modals, applying a z-index in CSS will work, however, I have run into the other modal shining through.

A quick code example of the panel with two children would be:

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlParent" runat="server">
<asp:panel id="pnlChild1" runat="server" visible="false">
... controls ...
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="pnlChild2" runat="server" visible="false">
</asp:panel>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender id="mpePnlParent" runat="server" ...other attributes .../>
```

Now, on the first button click, set the visibility of pnlchild1 to true.  The onclick event of the pnlChild1's button will set the visibility of pnlChild1 to false, the visibility of pnlChild2 to true.

finally, on whatever action completes the 2nd child panel, hide both children panels and hide the modalpopup with the .Hide() method of the panel.

Here is some CSS to try on the modal popup to gray out the main screen background, and "highlight" the modal content

```
.modalBackground
{
    background-color: #000011;
    -moz-opacity: .60;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: .60;
}
.modalPopup
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px outset #00F;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 640px;
}
```

The above CSS is cross browser safe.

Good Luck